# Display filtered objects/arrays created by child component into the parent component

Tags: reactjs

I am new to ReactJS but learned tons of things lately. I created a SearchBar React component so I can filter my array. Once I start entering a value in the input text box, the filteredObjects becomes smaller when the string is a match. That's good and it's working.

However, what I can't figure out is how can my parent component rerender the new value that I filtered? I want the values of filteredObjects to be rendered on the screen.

This is my parent component

```js
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'CommentBox',

  getInitialState: function() {
    return { 
      responseText: []
    }
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    var self = this;
    fetch.get(url).then(function (response) {
      self.setState({responseText: response.data.logs});
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  },

render: function() {
  let msg = this.state.responseText.map((m, i) => <tr key={i}><td>{m.timestamp}</td>);

  return (
    <div>
    <SearchBar logs={this.state.responseText} />
    <table>
      <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Timestamp</th>
      </tr>
      {msg}
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
  );
}
});
```

The SearchBar component code is below

```js
var SearchBar = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { findQuery: ''};
  },

  onUpdate: function(event) {
    this.setState({findQuery: event.target.value});

    var filteredObjects = this.props.logs.filter(function(obj) {
      var matched = false;
      Object.keys(obj).some(function(key) {
        if (obj[key].indexOf(event.target.value) > -1) {
          matched = true;
          return true;
        }
      });
      return matched;
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    var value = this.state.findQuery;
    return <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." value={value} onChange={this.onUpdate} />;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that adds the matched objects into the parents state, and passes a method to update it as a prop to the child. From here, you should be able to use `this.state.filteredResponses` to update the `msg` and display the data.

Parent

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({

  displayName: 'CommentBox',

  getInitialState: function() {
    return { 
      allResponses: [],
      filteredResponses: []
    }
  },

  updateFiltered: function(query) {
    var filteredObjects = this.state.filteredResponses.filter(function(obj) {
      var matched = false;
      Object.keys(obj).some(function(key) {
        if (obj[key].indexOf(event.target.value) > -1) {
          matched = true;
          return true;
        }
      });
      return matched;
    });

    this.setState({filteredResponses: filteredObjects));
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    var self = this;
    fetch.get(url).then(function (response) {
      self.setState({allResponses: response.data.logs});
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  },

render: function() {
  const responses = this.state.filteredResponses.length ? this.state.filteredResponses : this.state.allResponses;
  const msg = responses.map((m, i) => <tr key={i}><td>{m.timestamp}</td>);

  return (
    <div>
    <SearchBar updateFiltered={this.updateFiltered} />
    <table>
      <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Timestamp</th>
      </tr>
      {msg}
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
  );
}
});
```

Child

```
var SearchBar = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { findQuery: ''};
  },

  onUpdate: function(event) {
    this.setState({findQuery: event.target.value});
    this.props.updateFiltered(event.target.value);
  },

  render: function() {
    var value = this.state.findQuery;
    return <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." value={value} onChange={this.onUpdate} />;
  }
});
```

Comment: Just noticed, if it doesn't work you may need to bind the passed helper function like so: `updateMatched={this.updateMatched.bind(this)}`. Let me know if this is the case and I'll update the answer.

Comment: it's actually calling the this.updateMatched with the earlier code you wrote. However, it's not updating the webpage because the msg is the one that gets updated. So I'm not sure how to update {msg} with the new value we got in matched in updateMatched method.

Comment: With the change you made, this.updateMatched.bind(this), it's not working too and I see a Warning: bind() in console

Comment: I'm also wondering now with the code above, when I type in the textbox, it takes at least 2 seconds before the character shows up. It's slow. It wasn't like this before.

Comment: In order to update the list properly when we change the search value, we need to keep track of full list as well as the filtered list. Since we have two lists, we'll have to change the `msg` logic to use the filtered list if it's filtered or the full list if it's not. As far as the lag, that's likely from both components re-rendering on every keypress when they don't need to. We can update the `shouldComponentUpdate` method to determine when they should be updating. Give me a few minutes to update my answer.

Comment: I've updated with the `msg` logic. I also moved some of the logic that was in the child into the parent. For the reason why I moved that logic give [this](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.sc5r6amwe) a skim. If it doesn't work, try it again with binding and then report back!

Comment: looking now and I'll keep you posted